# two variables in front of update_or_create

Tags: django

I've come across the following line of code

```
_, created = UserProfile.objects.update_or_create(
```

What is the point of the "_"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_or_create` returns a tuple. The first value is the object, the second value is a bool that is `True` if the object is created and `False` if it was updated.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/

`_` is a variable that is commonly used in python to denote this particular value is being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

[**`.update_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) returns a 2-tuple:

> Returns a **tuple of `(object, created)`**, where `object` is the created or updated object and `created` is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

Here one uses [*iterable unpacking* [pep-3132]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to unpack the 2-tuple and assign the first and second value of the 2-tuple to a variable named `_` and `created` respectively.

Often variables like `_` and `__` are used for values for which we are not interested. It is thus used as a "throwaway" variable that is necessary to unpack the 2-tuple.

Here likely the rest of the function is only interested in the value for `created`, not in the created or updated object.